# Are these logical variables for predicting among train/test sets?

Tags: model, logic

I'm wondering if the following makes sense for a model.

I have a training and a test set. I want to predict whether a website visitor is a bot or a human, based on several visits. The data has been classified, so in the training set I know whether they are humans or bots.

There is 63% of overlap in the IP-addresses of the training and test set.

I also know that an IP address is not purely decisive whether someone is a bot or human.

I'm thinking to take the average of the bot outcome of the ip-address, not taking into account the row itself for the training as a feature:

```
ip  bot  feature
1   1     0.5    # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding a bot=1)
1   1     0.5    # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding a bot=1)
1   0      1     # (avg of 1 & 1, excluding a bot=0)
2   1     0.5    # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding a bot=1)
2   0      1     # (avg of 1 & 1, excluding a bot=0)
2   1     0.5    # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding a bot=1)
```

For the test, it can then just use the average of "bot" outcome per IP-address in the training set (or the global average if no ip does not occur in training), and a dummy variable for being in the test or not.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Some brainwaves: make sure that you have "unknown IP adresses" in your training set. Modelling an unknown IP address as .5 might be an option, this basically says "we do not have any information". Deviations from 0.5 point in either direction. Grtz from Amsterdam.

Comment: Alternatively, you could build two models: one for known and one for unknown IP addresses.

Comment: @sprdnl I chose to do the average bot-ness as "I do not know". The feature seems to get an AUC of 0.87 on its own with a random cross validation: I'm a bit suspicious. 0.87 is not so impressive in fact.